# Automatically fills the column based on the selection of choice column in the sharepoint list 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-foundation

I have one custom list built in sharepoint 2010 which is choice column.

The Datas of the list are

1.ABC

2.CDE

3.DEF

4.DFG

5.VFG

I need only numbers be automatically fills that in column when adding new item in the list.

for e.g: if i select "1.ABC",I need to fill that column field as only 1,

if i select "2.CDE",I need to fill that column field as only 2,

if i select "3.DEF",I need to fill that column field as only 3,

if i select "4.DFG",I need to fill that column field as only 4,

if i select "5.VFG",I need to fill that column field as only 5,

How can i achieve my requirement?

Please Help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simplet approach is to just have the values you need in the column and put the ABC, DEF, etc in the help description for th users to relate the two together.

Otherwise, you'll need a second "calculated" column to strip out the number OR you are looking at a code based option.

Comment: I need to go with second "calculated" column. May i know how to achieve this using formula.

Comment: If your column is called "ChoiceCol" then the calculated column formula would be =LEFT(ChoiceCol,1) or if the text is not as described above, maybe you'll need to split the string. From the example above, this will work though.